# how to make straight columns

Tags: alignment

I cannot understand how to make such columns
[image]

like this. Seems that align doesn't help (?)

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SE! Did you try the `tabular` environment?

Comment: I can't figure out how to make the first letter of each column line up. Also, is there any way to increase the spacing between the columns?

Comment: How can we tell you what is wrong with your code if you do not show any code? `\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{2cm}}l}` would be a two column table with 2cm space between the columns.

Comment: `\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{ c c c c }
 \textbf{Affirmative} & \textbf{Negative}& \textbf{Interrogative }& \textbf{Short Answers} \\
 I am & I am not & am I? & No, I'm not. \\
 
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}`

Comment: For the alignment of the first letters in each column, use the table preamble `{llll}`, not `{cccc}`.

Comment: So, how do you increase the spacing between columns? \hspace doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, to left-justify your columns, use `\begin{tabular}{l l l l}` instead of `\begin{tabular}{c c c c}`. The `c` is for center-justified columns.

There are several ways to change spacing between columns. One way is to add `@{\hspace{1cm}}` between each `l`, which will set the spacing between columns to 1 cm. Of course, you can set the spacing however you like—they can be the same or different for each space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l @{\hspace{1cm}} l @{\hspace{1cm}} l @{\hspace{1cm}} l}
    \textbf{Affirmative} & \textbf{Negative}& \textbf{Interrogative }& \textbf{Short Answers} \\
    I am & I am not & am I? & No, I'm not. \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```